# Как заставить хром запомнить мои данные из автокомплита?

Tags: html, html5, google-chrome, frontend

Есть у тега input атрибут autocomplete, вот по нему доки. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#autofill-field

И эти поля прекрасно подставляют информацию, если она есть в профиле гугловского аккаунта. Но ведь если там данных нет, то они должны запоминаться после формы и быть доступными для подстановки при следующем вводе. Верно?

Сама форма имеет  autocomplete="on"

Так как заставить хром *shut up and take my data*?

Comment: вероятно, у вас просто в настройках браузера автозаполнение выключено

Comment: @koroche_vot, http://prntscr.com/i59r78

Comment: не понимаю в чем  трабл, в песочнице работает https://jsfiddle.net/4n69s6sg/

Comment: @koroche_vot, спасибо, видимо локально какие то проблемы были, теперь хоть тестировать могу

Comment: тогда, если не сложно - отметьте ответ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php" autocomplete="on">
  First name:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  E-mail: <input type="email" name="email"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```